# Parse-server SSL IIS

Tags: rest, parsing, ssl, iis, parse-server

I have tried using serverURL as localhost:1337/parse and publicServerURL as https://mydomaindotcom:1337/parse but I don't know how parse is recognizing the certificate.  I don't see a config value to set the cert for parse-server.

Also tried adding cert to IIS 7 to a website on port 443 and using URL Rewrite 2.0 to localhost:1337/parse.

I'm running a self-hosted parse instance using node.  parse-server is installed globally.  I'm using a config file to start to instance.

Server works fine on http, however I need to utilize https so I can use the rest or js api key without passing headers like so https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@mydomaindotcom/classes/GameScore/Ed1nuqPvcm

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an https binding that references port 1337 if that is the one that you want to use.

Comment: I can't set a binding for that port as it fails since node is already using that port to serve the parse-server.  I have tried setting a binding to the default 443 port and using URL Rewrite to 127.0.0.1:1337 and i just get a blank page.  Before doing this I was getting a 404.  I'm afraid now the binding is taking over but not redirecting to the localhost.